# Next Auth google OAuth with custom backend access token

Tags: authentication, next.js, oauth-2.0, nest, next-auth

I have a `NestJS` backend that has its own authentication in jwt
and `NextJs` + `next-auth` application and I want to implement login by Google functionality but next auth is using its own generated token I want `next-auth` to use my own access tokens from the `NestJS` backend, how can I do that?

I tried to put the callback URL to the backend to send the authenticated user to the backend and redirect the request to the next auth callback with the user from the database with the custom-generated token

next-auth Provider

```
GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          request_uri: `${process.env.BACKEND_URL}/auth/google/callback`,
        },
      },
    }),
```

in Nest

```
@Public()
    @Get('google/callback')
    @UseGuards(GoogleOAuthGuard)
    @Redirect('f')
    googleAuthRedirect(@Request() req) {
        console.log('success');
        return null;
        // return this.appService.googleLogin(req);
    }
```

but after the user login with his Google account, I got an error from the backend

```
missing code verifier
```

How can I tell `next-auth` to store the user from the nest backend database that is authenticated by Google, not the user is returned by Google?